# Combine multiple aliases of the same @Entity in one result with HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have the following pattern

```
@Entity
Class Fruit {
   String name;
}

@Entity
Class FruitAddition {
   @ManyToOne
   Basket basket;

   @ManyToOne
   Fruit fruit;

   String additionType;
}

@Entity
Class Basket {
   String owner;

   @ManyToMany   
   List<Fruit> fruits;

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy="basket")
   List<FruitAddition> fruitAdditions;
}
```

So the `Basket` is made out of a list of `Fruit`s (one fruit can be in many baskets at the same time) and of a list of `FruitAddition`s, which is almost a list of `Fruit`s, but each fruit in the basket has additional data `additionType` associated to it.

This seems to work.

**Now I want to query all the fruits** in a basket and thus I try to combine two aliases into one result as follows:

```
SELECT fruitAlone, fruitAdded 
FROM Basket bask 
JOIN bask.fruits fruitAlone 
JOIN bask.fruitAdditions addition 
JOIN addition.fruit fruitAdded
WHERE bask.owner = 'JOE'
```

And then interpret the result as a `List<Fruit>`, since both `fruitAlone` and `fruitAdded` are of type `Fruit`.

But I get a `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

How is this correctly done?

Answer (score 1):

You can just receive a `List<Object[]>`, where the first position will be the `fruitAlone` and the second the `fruitAdded`. Like:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT fruitAlone, fruitAdded ...");
List<Object[]> results = query.getResultList();
for (Object[] obj : results) {
    Fruit fruitAlone= obj[0];
    Fruit fruitAdded = obj[1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test it tomorrow. Do you know what will happen to paging (LIMIT) ? Will the size be applied to both aliases?